# What is a good strategy for es6 integration?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

when I do not want to use a transpiler.  I want to write straight Javascript?  For example if I feature detect that `let` is available, so what I can not re-write my code to use block level scoping.

For example when should I start using let?  Is it even possible to form a general strategy?

Comment: Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility) and decide when you need to use it ie. it depends what browser you want to target for your users. Or, you may even find pollyfills... Just google...

Comment: I don't want to user transpilers or polyfills, and I don't want to subjectively decide that today is a good day.  what is a good strategy or objective test for beginning to write code with new features from es6 ...

Answer (score 1):

Feature detection doesn't really work for **syntax**. While you can test for syntax features using `eval` and `try...catch`, you cannot use that information to write your code one way or the other. It also doesn't really make sense to write the same code twice but with different syntax.

If you don't want to use a transpiler, you will simply have to avoid using any ES6 features until your target audience uses browsers that support it.

> Is it even possible to form a general strategy?

One way would be to say that you are going to use feature X if Y% of your visitors use a browser that support it. But that also means that your site might not properly work for (100-Y)% of your visitors.

That's exactly the problem transpilers are solving...

Comment: It *might* make sense to "feature"- or browser-detect and then dynamically load ES6 code that runs faster because of the native implementation. But you're right, even then you would let a transpiler generate the ES5 version of the code instead of writing it by hand.